# Determining which of the given values are not in the range of $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 3x + 2}{x^2 + x - 6}$

Tags: functions

Given $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{{x^2} - 3x + 2}}{{{x^2} + x - 6}}$ then the value(s) which $f(x)$ cannot take is

(A) $\frac{1}{5}$

(B) $1$

(C) $\frac{2}{3}$

(D) $-\frac{1}{5}$

This is a multiple choice question having more than one option.

My solution is as follows: $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{{x^2} - 3x + 2}}{{{x^2} + x - 6}} = \frac{{{x^2} - 2x - x + 2}}{{{x^2} + 3x - 2x - 6}} \Rightarrow f\left( x \right) = \frac{{\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right)}}{{\left( {x + 3} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right)}}$

$x \ne 2,x \ne  - 3,\frac{{{x^2} - 3x + 2}}{{{x^2} + x - 6}} = m \Rightarrow {x^2} - 3x + 2 = m{x^2} + mx - 6m \Rightarrow {x^2}\left( {m - 1} \right) + \left( {m + 3} \right)x - 6m - 2 = 0$

For real roots of $x$, ${\left( {m + 3} \right)^2} + 4\left( {m - 1} \right)\left( {6m + 2} \right) \ge 0 \Rightarrow {m^2} + 6m + 9 + 4\left( {6{m^2} - 4m - 2} \right) \ge 0$

$ \Rightarrow 25{m^2} - 10m + 1 \ge 0 \Rightarrow {m^2} - 2 \times \frac{1}{5}m + \frac{1}{{25}} \ge 0$

${\left( {m - \frac{1}{5}} \right)^2} \ge 0$, but the answer is wrong. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You implicitly assume $m-1\ne 0$. What if $m-1=0$?

Comment: Notice that if $x=2$, your function is undefined, and otherwise it is equal to $\frac{x-1}{x+3}$. This is an alternative, but probably simpler approach. But I think the above comment is also sufficient to fix your solution. Also, don't forget to check which values of $m$ you get when $x=2, x=-3$ and whether you have to throw them out.

Comment: Yes but has more that 1 choice f(x)=1 is not possible as x approaches infinity

Comment: I don't understand your solution.  Shouldn't we be solving for $m$ in terms of $x$ rather than for $x$ in terms of $m$?

Comment: These type of question I used this technique to find the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a few readings to figure out your reasoning, but you correctly stated that

$f(x) =m$ is possible if and only if

$x^2(m-1) +(m+3)x -(6m+2) =0$ has real roots other than $x=2$ or $x=-3$.

But you assumed that $x^2(m-1) +(m+3)x -(6m+2)$ is always a quadratic.

If $m=1$ then that equation is linear equation $4x -8=0$ with $x=2$ which is ruled out as $x=2$ is an unacceptable root.

So $m=1$ is not a possible outcome.

If $m\ne 1$ then this has real roots when the descriminant $(m+3)^2 + 4(6m+2)(m-1)=(m-\frac 15)^2 \ge 0$. This is always the case... but we must not have the roots be $2$ or $-3$

So we can not allow the roots of $x = \frac {-(m+3)\pm (m-\frac 15)}{2(m-1)}$ to be entirely contained by $x=2$ or $-3$.

If we have $\frac {-(m+3)+(m-\frac 15)}{2(m-1)}= \frac{-\frac {16}5}{2(m-1)}=\frac 8{5(1-m)}=2$ then $\frac 45=1-m$ and $m=\frac 15$.  In which case the "other" root of $\frac{-(m+3)-(m-\frac 15)}{2(m-1)}$ is also $2$.  So $m=\frac 15$ is not a possible outcome.

If we have $\frac {-(m+3)+(m-\frac 15)}{2(m-1)}=\frac 8{5(1-m)}=-3$ then $m-1=\frac 8{15}$ and $m=\frac {23}{15}$.  However this is acceptable if the "other" root of $x = \frac{-(m+3)-(m-\frac 15)}{2(m-1)}=\frac {2m + \frac {14}5}{2(1-m)}= \frac {m+\frac 75}{1-m}=\frac {5m + 7}{5(1-m)}\ne 2,-3$.  And indeed $x=\frac {5\cdot \frac {23}{15} + 7}{5(1-\frac {23}{15}}= \frac{\frac{23}3 +7}{-\frac{8}3}=-\frac{23+21}8=\frac {11}2$ is perfectly valid input  (and $f(\frac {11}2)= \frac {23}{15}$.

Similarly if we have $\frac {-(m+3)-(m-\frac 15)}{2(m-1)}=\frac {m-\frac 75}{1-m}=-3$ we get another acceptable $\frac {-(m+3)+(m-\frac 15)}{2(m-1)}\ne 2,-3$.  I'll leave it to you.
......

It would have been *much* easier to have "canceled" the $x-2$.

$x\ne 2,x\ne -3$ and $f(x) = \frac {(x-1)(x-2)}{(x+3)(x-2)} =\frac{(x-1)}{(x+3)}=m$ will exist so long $x-1 = m(x+3)$ or in other words $x(1-m)=3m+1$ has solutions other than $x=2,x=-3$.

This has solutions precisely when $m\ne 1$ and $x=\frac {3m+1}{1-m}$ or when $m=1$ and $x\times 0 = 4$.  As $x\times 0 = 4$ is never achieved we can not have $m=1$.

If $m\ne 1$ and $x = \frac {3m+1}{1-m}$ will have values for all other values of $m$ so all other values are achievable unless $x =2,-3$.

If $x=\frac {3m+1}{1-m}=2$ then $3m+1 = 2(1-m)$ and $m=\frac 15$ is not allowed.

If $x =\frac{3m+1}{1-m}=-3$ then $3m+1 =3m-1$ or $0=2$ is not allowed.

So $m=1$ and $m=\frac 15$ are the only two values not reached.

...

Even is noting that if $x\ne 2,-3$ then $f(x) =\frac {x-1}{x+3}= \frac {x+3}{x+3} - 4{x+3} = 1-\frac 4{x+3}= m$ is possible when $\frac 4{x+3} = 1-m$ so $x = \frac 4{1-m}-3$.

If we rule out $x=\frac 4{1-m}-3=2$ so $\frac 4{1-m}=5$ and $m = \frac 15$ is out.

Comment: Very nice explanation to the problem

Answer (score 1):

For $x\ne 2$ we have:

$
\frac{x-1}{x+3}= \frac{1}{5} \Rightarrow 5x-5=x+3 \Rightarrow x=2
$
Since we need $x\ne 2$ the value $x=\frac{1}{5}$ cannot be taked.

$
\frac{x-1}{x+3}= 1 \Rightarrow x-1=x+3 \Rightarrow -1=3
$
so also this value canon be taken...

...And so one.....

Answer (score 0):

We are given that

$$ f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2+x-1} $$

But this is equivalent to

$$ f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x+3}\text{ for } x\ne2$$

Since $f$ is undefined for $x=2$ it can never take on the value of $\dfrac{2-1}{2+3}=\dfrac{1}{5}$.